# Can't build for prod, primeng datascroller template parse error

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to build our Angular 7.1.1 application for prod. I am getting the following error:

`ERROR in : Template parse errors:
The pipe 'slice' could not be found ("ght': scrollHeight}">
            <ul class="ui-datascroller-list">
                <li *ngFor="let [ERROR ->]item of value | slice:first:(first + (page * rows)); trackBy: trackBy; let i = index">
              "): /Users/appdev/Documents/Wakanda/solutions/plannerTool4/web/node_modules/primeng/components/datascroller/datascroller.d.ts.DataScroller.html@7:32`

I googled and I don't see this issue come up so I am leaning towards it being a problem on my end.

I got this error when I was using primeng 6.1.0  and thought that updating to 7.0.0 might fix. I tried updating a lot of other things, like my angular devDependencies, but did not resolve.

Comment: Are you trying to use Ivy?

Comment: @IrvLennert Yes, setting the `enableIvy` to `false` in my `tsconfig.json` allowed me to build. Thank you!

Comment: @irvLennert if you want to answer the question I'll mark it the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like you (probably thought), they were using the Ivy renderer in Angular version 7.  It is still a work in progress and, if you have it enabled in the tsconfig.json, you will have some very strange problems, it will not give you any helpful errors.  I suggest to disable it...  That fixed my problems...